# vue js check all images with class have loaded

Tags: vue.js

```html
<template v-for="(option, oid) in currentStepOptions[preselect.step]">
    <div class="preselectbox" v-if="hasOptionImage(option)"  v-bind:key="oid">
        <div v-bind:class="isSelectedImageClass(preselect.id, option.id)">
            <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="selectOption(option, preselect.id, preselect.step)">
                <img  v-bind:src="resolveOptionImage(option)" v-bind:data-option-id="option.id" class="preselect-image">
            </a>
        </div>
        <span class="preselect-name">{{ option.description }}</span>
        <span v-if="optionHasInformation(option)" class="">{{ option.information }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="preselectbox text-only" v-bind:key="oid">
        <div class="preselect-text" v-bind:class="isSelectedClass(preselect.id, option.id)" v-on:click="selectOption(option, preselect.id, preselect.step)">
            {{ option.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

How can i check that all images above with class preselect-image have loaded before calling a function?

Comment: if the answer does help you, accept the Answer and give a comment on it :)  The way I introduced is quite promising and opens other use-cases, too. HF

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky but not impossible.
I had a similar task and used the `onload` event to get the landscape of a given image. In your case you can check if the image is loaded correctly or set a fallback image accordingly or modify the Classes of the image tag, or whatever you want.

As you have your elements in your v-for, you could take advantage of `this.$refs` and apply the onload event on it and handle anything you want after that.

Note, that I have created a Component `ImageCover` that does handle all the image checking, rendering, etc. per Image.

In Your Template

```html
<template>
...
<img :src="cover" ref="image" v-show="!error" />
...
</template>
```

And all the logics goes here into the `appendNativeImageEventListeners` method.

```js
<script>
export default {
   name: 'ImageCover',
   props: ['cover'],

   data: { return {
      height: null,
      width: null,
      error: null,
   }},

   mounted(){
       this.appendNativeImageEventListeners()
   },

   methods: {
        appendNativeImageEventListeners(){
            // picking up the native image tag
            let img = this.$refs.image 

            // console warn for good manner
            if( !img ){
                return console.warn("image ref not rendered....:")
            }

            // apply event listener on error
            img.onerror = (e)   =>  {
                console.warn('Error loading', e)
                this.error = e

                // if you want another fallback image, you 
                // could set it here with this.cover = "xxx"
                // you probably want to handle this as a computed property
            }

            // add onload event, means when the image is loaded
            img.onload = (e) => {
                // console.log("loaded ?", e, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)
                this.width = img.naturalWidth 
                this.height = img.naturalHeight   

                // in this state the image is fully loaded
                // do whatever you want with the image
                // or set a dynamicClass property and modify it              
            }
        },

}
</script>
```